# why is my dropdown selection not being submitted?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list when the form is submitted it is submitted null...

html:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => Model.HowOftenCar, Model.HowOftenCar, new { id = "CompDrop" })
```

Model:

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> HowOftenCar { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
IList<string> HowOftenCar = new List<string>();
HowOftenCar.Insert(0, "More than once a week");
HowOftenCar.Insert(1, "Once a month");
HowOftenCar.Insert(2, "Once a year");
model.HowOftenCar = HowOftenCar.Select(c => new SelectListItem()
{
  Text = c,
  Value = c
});
```

Post:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(Competition model)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {}
 }
```

I have also tried...

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(c => Model.HowOftenCar, new SelectList(Model.HowOftenCar, "Value","Text"), new { id = "CompDrop" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `DropDownListFor` correctly.

The first parameter is the property on the model you want to populate. If you want to populate the `HowOftenCar` property on the model, it should be of the type of the value - in this case, it looks like a string.

```
public string HowOftenCar { get; set; }
```

The second parameter is the list of choices. You've got that right, but it needs to be something else than the property you're trying to set.

```
IList<string> HowOftenCarChoices = new List<string>
{
    "More than once a week", 
    "Once a month",
    "Once a year"
};

model.HowOftenCarChoices = HowOftenCar.Select(c => new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = c,
    Value = c
});
```

So then you'll end up with

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HowOftenCar, Model.HowOftenCarChoices)
```

Note that you don't need the id property, because `DropDownListFor` will automatically give it the id of `HowOftenCar`, based on the lambda.

Comment: sorry dont understand...ur setting model.HowOftenCarChoises, but this is not in the model? only HowOftenCar is?

Comment: I just put it on the model to get it to the view. You could put it on ViewData or ViewBag if you want. Or define the choices in the view itself. Either way, that object needs to be passed to DropDownFor.